# Passing "this" as root to LayoutInflater.inflate() in a custom component

Tags: android, custom-component, layout-inflater

I am writing the code for a custom component that extends LinearLayout.  It will include a Spinner at the top, and some number of settings below, depending on what the Spinner is set to.  i.e., when the user selects "Apple" on the spinner, a "color" option appears, and when they select "Banana" a "length" option appears.

Since a spinner option might have many settings associated with it, I define each group of settings in a layout XML with "merge" as the root tag.  Then I call initViews() in each constructor to inflate the views so I can add/remove them later.

Here is the code for the class:

```
    public class SchedulePickerView extends LinearLayout {
        protected Context context;

        protected Spinner typeSpinner;
        protected ViewGroup defaultSetters;  // ViewGroup to show when no schedule is selected in the spinner
        protected ViewGroup simpleSetters;   // ViewGroup to show when SimpleSchedule is selected in the spinner

        public SchedulePickerView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
            initViews();
        }

        public SchedulePickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
            super(context, attr);
            this.context = context;
            initViews();
        }

        public SchedulePickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defstyle) {
            super(context, attr, defstyle);
            this.context = context;
            initViews();
        }

        private void initViews() {
            // Init typeSpinner
            typeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.schedulepickerSpinner);

            // Init setters (ViewGroups that show settings for the various types of schedules
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            // ERROR IS ON THIS LINE:
            defaultSetters = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_schedulesetter_default, this);
        }
   }
```

I get this error on the marked line: "Incompatible types: Required = ViewGroup, Found = View".  But LinearLayout extends ViewGroup, as per [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) documentation.  I have even tried casting "this" to a ViewGroup, but strangely the IDE greyed-out the cast (since, obviously, every LinearLayout is already a ViewGroup).  So why is there an issue?

Comment: try using the classname.this

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: Please attach your full control code.

Comment: @ligi have edited the post to include the surrounding code and the error I am getting.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inflate()` returns a `View` and you're trying to assign it to a more specific `ViewGroup` variable. It's not the `this` as parent view that is problematic - you need a cast on the return value:

```
defaultSetters = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(...)
```

Comment: Of course!  I thought the IDE was saying the method call itself was an error, but it was the variable assignment.  Thank you!